# Python: search string in a txt file always results in not finding

Tags: python

I have been trying to debug my code for searching strings in two files, but I can't understand why the strings are not found all the time. I have been stuck here for half day, and probably you could help me to understand the error, please?

The logic is: (after filtering out line in "try_ID.txt" by this piece `len(re.findall("Ca", row)) == 0 or len(re.findall("Co", row)) == 0`), if ca and co in "try_ID.txt" do not appear in both "try.txt" and "try_C.txt", then we go into the first if condition in my code; if we only find either ca or co in "try.txt" or "try_C.txt", then it goes into the `elif` conditions in my code; if we find both ca and co in both files "try_C.txt" and "try.txt", then we go into `else` condition in my code.

The problem is that, with my code, all the items go into the first if conditions (both not found). I don't know why.

**my code**

```
import re


with open("try_ID.txt", 'r') as fin, \
        open("try_C.txt", 'r') as co_splice, \
        open("try.txt", 'r') as ca_splice:
    for row in fin:
        if len(re.findall("Ca", row)) == 0 or len(re.findall("Co", row)) == 0:
            pass 
        else: # problem starts from here
            name = str(row.split()[1]) + "_blast"
            if not row.split()[1] in ca_splice.read() and not row.split()[2] in co_splice.read():
                print(row.split()[0:2])
            elif row.split()[1] in ca_splice.read() and not row.split()[2] in col_splice.read(): 
                print(row.split()[1] + "Ca")
            elif not row.split()[1] in can_splice.read() and row.split()[2] in col_splice.read(): 
                print(row.split()[2] + "Co")
            else: 
                ne_name = name + "recip"
                print(ne_name)
```

**"try_ID.txt"**

```
H21911        Ca29092.1t    A05340.1
H21912        Ca19588.1t    Co27353.1t    A05270.1
H21913        Ca19590.1t    Co14899.1t    A05260.1
H21914        Ca19592.1t    Co14897.1t    A05240.1
H21915    Co14877.1t    A05091.1
S25338  Ca12595.1t  Co27352.1t  A53970.1
S20778  Ca29091.1t  Co24326.1t  A61120.1
S26552  Ca20916.1t  Co14730.1t  A16155.1
```

**"try_C.txt"**

```
Co14730.1t;Co14730.2t
Co27352.1t;Co27352.2t;Co27352.3t;Co27352.4t;Co27352.5t
Co14732.1t;Co14732.2t
Co4217.1t;Co4217.2t
Co27353.1t;Co27353.2t
Co14733.1t;Co14733.2t
```

**"try.txt"**

```
Ca12595.1t;Ca12595.2t
Ca29091.1t;Ca29091.2t
Ca1440.1t;Ca1440.2t
Ca29092.1t;Ca29092.2t
Ca20916.1t;Ca20916.2t
```

Though weird thing is when I try a small piece of code like below, it can find the strings.

```
row = "H20118        Ca12595.1t    Co18779.1t    A01010.1"
text_file = "try.txt"
with open(text_file, 'r') as fin:
    if row.split()[1] in fin.read():
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

I really don't understand.

Comment: You're calling `.read()` on a file multiple times. After the first call the rest will return an empty string. Also, `if not row.split()[1] in ca_splice.read()`, etc.. should be `if row.split()[1] not in ca_splice.read()`.

Comment: If you're trying to read the file line by line, you don't want to use `read`.

Comment: Your "small piece of code" is almost 100% different from your real world scenario. Use version control and then reduce your code step by step until the error disappears. Then revert to the revision before. That way you have a [mre] that you can give us.

Comment: Thanks @Axe319! I tried to called `co_splice_db =  ca_splice.read()`, and then use `co_splice_db` for the following code, but it still got the same problem. Could you give me a bit more info to improve it?

Comment: Thanks @MarkRansom! I also try .readlines(). Is better to use this?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWeller for the fast reply! The example I give here is error-reproducible example with my code. Not the "small piece of code" though. :)

Comment: "Is better to use this?" - read about it, understand what it does. Understand what your code did before and then judge yourself.

Comment: The code you gave us ("my code") does not seem to be minimal. If I understood the problem correctly, the last 10 lines of the code can be minimized to `print("unexpected")`

Comment: @ThomasWeller sorry, probably I didn't explain very well, or because I'm new to this. The last 10 lines in "my code" actually is the major part of what I would like to do, as it separates conditions by whether we find the records from "try_ID.txt" in other two files. For each condition, I actually have other functions to to deal with. But here I only use `print()` to test whether the `if` conditions work correctly. The result shows no, and that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read and split and search only once wherever possible. Try to keep it simple.

```
with open("try_ID.txt", 'r') as fin, \
        open("try_C.txt", 'r') as co_splice, \
        open("try.txt", 'r') as ca_splice:
    co_splice = co_splice.read()
    ca_splice = ca_splice.read()
    for row in fin:
        if 'Ca' in row or 'Co' in row:
            zero,one,two,*_ = row.split()
            name = one + "_blast"
            one_in_ca = one in ca_splice
            two_in_co = two in co_splice
            if not one_in_ca and not two_in_co:
                print(zero,one,two)
            elif one_in_ca and not two_in_co: 
                print(one + "Ca")
            elif not one_in_ca and two_in_co: 
                print(two + "Co")
            else: 
                ne_name = name + "recip"
                print(ne_name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I know moving `co_splice = co_splice.read()` out of the for loop is the key! Now I also finally understand what @Axe319 mentioned above about .read() too many times. I thought it's only about the .read() in the for loop. Also thank you for this `zero,one,two,*_ = row.split()`! I didn't really know how to use it in my code until now. :)